# How to read an octet string from file

Tags: python, string

I have a base64 encoded octet string in a file:

> \x7D\x1E\x40\xEE\x62\x12\xE1\x9C\xC9\x28\x63\x95\xB6\x0C\xCB\xF7\xD2\x2F\x6F\xA8\xA1\xF5
>   \x21\x4E\x7A\x4D\x79\x38\x78\xBF\x1B\x2B\x73\x28\x57\x5C\x8F\xB2\x53\xC0\x4C\x57\x6C\x77
>   \xCF\x88\xA3\xAA\x7D\x52\xEA\x2F\xCD\xE9\x29\x27\xD9\x0F\xA1\xF4\x12\xDB\xBF\x65\x09\x4C
>   \x29\xE9\xC9\xB5\x0F\x3C\xE5\xEC\x82\xBC\x42\x3C\xBB\xE2\xFF\x7B\x7B\xB1\x32\x3F\x4D\xC5
>   \x14\x66\x69\x98\x0C\x43\xB1\xE2\x9D\x7F\x63\xEF\xF5\xB1\xEA\xA0\xDC\x58\x8B\x1F\x9E\xE1
>   \x12\x14\xA3\xD2\x73\x27\x73\xE5\xC8\x2B\xBD\x0A\x0B\xE6\x05\x42\x36\x21

And I want to read it in Python. But Python automatically escapes the backslashes for me, thus I got the following string:

> \\x7D\\x1E\\x40\\xEE\\x62\\x12\\xE1\\x9C\\xC9\\x28\\x63\\x95\\xB6\\x0C\\xCB\\xF7\\xD2\\x2F\\x6F\\xA8\\xA1\\xF5\\x21\\x4E\\x7A\\x4D\\x79\\x38\\x78\\xBF\\x1B\\x2B\\x73\\x28\\x57\\x5C\\x8F\\xB2\\x53\\xC0\\x4C\\x57\\x6C\\x77\\xCF\\x88\\xA3\\xAA\\x7D\\x52\\xEA\\x2F\\xCD\\xE9\\x29\\x27\\xD9\\x0F\\xA1\\xF4\\x12\\xDB\\xBF\\x65\\x09\\x4C\\x29\\xE9\\xC9\\xB5\\x0F\\x3C\\xE5\\xEC\\x82\\xBC\\x42\\x3C\\xBB\\xE2\\xFF\\x7B\\x7B\\xB1\\x32\\x3F\\x4D\\xC5\\x14\\x66\\x69\\x98\\x0C\\x43\\xB1\\xE2\\x9D\\x7F\\x63\\xEF\\xF5\\xB1\\xEA\\xA0\\xDC\\x58\\x8B\\x1F\\x9E\\xE1\\x12\\x14\\xA3\\xD2\\x73\\x27\\x73\\xE5\\xC8\\x2B\\xBD\\x0A\\x0B\\xE6\\x05\\x42\\x36\\x21

And...

```
>>> repr(sig_bytes)
"'\\\\x7D\\\\x1E\\\\x40\\\\xEE\\\\x62\\\\x12...'"
>>> sig_bytes.replace("\\x","\x")
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

What should I do?

Comment: How are you loading the file?

Comment: @larsmans I use f=open("my_file"), s=f.read(), f.close(). Is that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may see the `repr()` version of your string displayed somewhere, which doesn't mean your string is incorrectly loaded:

```
>>> s = "\x7D\x1E\x40\xEE"
>>> s
'}\x1e@\xee'
>>> repr(s)
"'}\\x1e@\\xee'"
```

**Edit:**

If your string is already double-escaped and you want to remove those, use `replace`, and don't forget to escape the `\` also in the arguments:

```
sig_bytes.replace("\\\\x","\\x")
```

**Edit 2:**

OP is somehow getting the repr string loaded into its string variable instead of the correct string data.

```
s = "\\x7D\\x1E\\x40\\xEE"
```

Let's reinterpret this into the correct form OP should have loaded from the beginning. For this purpose we will construct a full string repr of the string by surrounding it with quotes, then ask `ast` module to `literal_eval` it:

```
import ast
s = "\\x7D\\x1E\\x40\\xEE"
s = '"'+s+'"'
s = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> s
'}\x1e@\xee'
```

Comment: @Mr.Teen you need to escape your backslashes in your arguments, see my update

Comment: It does not work. As you can see, there is only 1 backslash before every character 'x' in sig_bytes, so the replacement does not fit. What I really want is a single "\x" character, which is a string literal in Python that represents hex value, instead of a backslash plus an 'x'. See http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals for documentation.

Comment: @Mr.Teen See second update. You should really fix your loader anyway

Comment: Thanks! It works. I use f=open("my_file"), s=f.read(), f.close(). Is that wrong?